# I want to create a Web Service in PHP to process Paypal transactions

Tags: php, web-services, paypal

I want to create a Web Service in PHP where the client will send cart and other information.
The server (Web Service) then will perform the paypal transaction using Paypal API. After the transaction is complete the service will return the result and all values in JSON encoded format.

Step1: A site creates instance of Client and sends cart information to Service.
Step2: Services processes the information and performs paypal transaction (redirects to paypal site).
Step3: After paypal transaction is complete paypal returns to service.
Step4: Service processes the transaction information  (creates JSON) and returns to Client

The Service should be stand alone and can be used for any site.

Answer (score 0):

My [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make this very simple for you, as it basically does everything you're asking for here already.

You would just have to receive the data from your requesting client and then pass it into the library which has templates setup for nearly every API call PayPal offers.

It simply returns a PHP array of all the PayPal response data, so all you'd have to do is pass that into json_encode($paypal_response) to get your JSON string and output that for the requesting client.

You could have the whole thing ready to go in a matter of minutes depending on how much data you're receiving from the client.

Comment: Dear @andrew-angel 
I have downloaded and tried the library but could not run in localhost.
There are too many configurations.
Can you please send me the simple steps to run the application?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.angelleye.com/how-to-integrate-paypal-with-php-class-library/) for the library?

Comment: ok...well, I can't really provide any better steps than that.  Do you have any specific questions?